# Google-App-Engine and Cloud-Storage, Access Denied

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I have created a bucket in Cloud-Storage, and granted permission for my-gae-app (GAE), as Full_Control. I also configured CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) on my bucket for my-gae-app. I setup the bucket default ACL to have my-gae-app as owner.

In my-gae-app application, I have form to allow users to upload pdf/image to my-bucket. (I use GCS Client Library Functions) The upload process worked fine, when upload button is clicked, the file is written to my-bucket without error and I can verify from the cloud storage console that the files are there. I checked the files (object) permission, and I can see my-app-gae is the owner.

Other form which display those uploaded files are not working. Even as simple as "<"img src="https://storage.cloud.google.com/mybucket/my-uploaded-image.jpg"/">" 
The console show me that "GET ... 403 Forbidden". The page to show the pdf will display "Access Denied Access Denied".

I have tried to mark the object as "Shared Publicly" in the Cloud Storage console, than everything will work fine. But, this is not correct design. I need a solution to make my-bucket access by my-gae-app only, not publicly :o(

Can anyone please shed some light ? Much appreciated.

Comment: Well as per my knowledge and information, Google till now doesn't have any approach to access bucket by programmatically setting the **Shared Publicly** on your bucket files while uploading files through blobstore.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whatever "other form which display those uploaded files" is authenticated as needs to be on he access control list for that object with READ or FULL_CONTROL permission.  If you want that to be the case for all objects which you create in the bucket, the easiest way to do that is to set a Default Object Access Control for the bucket as described here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#default

With the default object access control set, you can grant READ by default to your form; you just need to find out which user/service account/group your form is authenticating as.

Comment: To add to this answer: <img> tags are usually rendered in a browser, so it is the users's browser which is making the HTTP request and getting the 403 error, not your GAE application. It sounds like you don't want to make the objects public, but you do want users of your GAE application to be able to see them? It's possible for your GAE application delegate access using public URLs which expire after a short time: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/accesscontrol#Signed-URLs

Comment: @Travis, thanks for your reply. I have setup the default access control for my bucket, which I make my app service account having FULL_CONTROL permission.  Can I know how to "grant READ by default to your form" ? Can you please share more ? Thanks for your help, very much appreciated....

Comment: @Brian, thanks for your reply and the suggestion for Signed-URLs, I will try this path...