# Can't access image files in Google Cloud storage from App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

Our GAE app has been running fine for years.  I'm trying to switch to IAM roles to manage buckets from the default (fine-grained access).  It doesn't work.

After switching to uniform access, I give StorageAdmin permissions to the GAE service account.  At that point our code fails in getServingUrl():

```
String filename = "/gs/" + bucketName + "/" + fileName;
String url = service.getServingUrl( ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(filename ));
```

An IllegalArgumentException is thrown with no detailed error message.

So, I play around with the permissions a bit more.  I add allUsers with StorageAdmin permissions to the bucket.  Two interesting things to note: 1) I can access the image directly from a browser using: https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket/filename.png.  2) Nothing changes on our app.  Still get the same behavior as described above!

To me, this makes no sense.  Doesn't allUsers mean anyone or any service can access the files?  And why doesn't adding the GAE service account work?

Comment: can you refer to the link : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48093210/gcp-app-engine-access-to-gcloud-storage-without-sharing-publicly Is it helpful?

Comment: Not really.  We want to use signed URLs but get access denied.  It seems like GAE is denied access.  That led to some experimentation in switching to uniform access.  When allUsers are allowed access, why can't GAE get access (even when I can access from web browser)?!?!

Comment: Actually, let me rephrase the initial question.  Can any google services (app engine, cloud functions, etc) access anything in cloud storage when only uniform access is used?  If so, how?

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of permissions allowed by the cloud storage to access any bucket or objects, these are IAM and ACLs , so if you are using IAM to access buckets then make sure that you are following the norm mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control#default) as:

> In most cases, IAM is the recommended method for controlling access to your resources. IAM controls permissioning throughout Google Cloud and
> allows you to grant permissions at the bucket and project levels. You should use IAM for any permissions that apply to multiple objects in a bucket to reduce
> the risks of unintended exposure. To use IAM exclusively, enable uniform bucket-level access to disallow ACLs for all Cloud Storage resources.
>
> If you use IAM and ACLs on the same resource, Cloud Storage grants the broader permission set on the resource. For example, if your IAM permissions only
> allow a few users to access my-object, but your ACLs make my-object public, then my-object is exposed to the public. In general, IAM cannot detect
> permissions granted by ACLs, and ACLs cannot detect permissions granted by IAM.

You can also refer to the [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18654610/google-app-engine-and-cloud-storage-access-denied) where a similar issue has been faced by the OP and got resolved by changing the permission in access control list of the object as READ or FULL_CONTROL.

Comment: @MikeDee posted an answer, Is it helpful?